# VBA paste value, format number and theme

Tags: excel, vba

i have a little problem with VBA. I want to paste data from one sheet and specific range to another sheet and last empty cell. I need to paste Value, Number format and theme. Is there any macro to select last paste range and paste into this range theme? Or is there any macro which can paste all data without formulas?

My code:

```
    Dim xScreenUpdating As Boolean
    Dim xPasteSht As Worksheet
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    On Error Resume Next
     Worksheets("KOPÍROVAT ASISTENT").Range("C1:G54").Copy
    Set xPasteSht = Worksheets("Archiv")
     xRg.Copy
    xPasteSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                 Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
          End Sub
```

Comment: would not a normal copy/paste work? Something like `PasteAll`?

Comment: Maybe `.PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` and `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` is what you're looking for. `kevin9999` has shown how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `.Offset(0,0)` achieves - `.Offset(1,0)` is what you actually need to find the `last empty cell`.  That aside, the following code snippet should give you what you want. Let me know how you go with it.

```
Sheets("KOPÍROVAT ASISTENT").Range("C1:G54").Copy

With Sheets("Archiv").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```